# Determining If a File Exists in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**Goal** : If the file exist, load the file, else load the `default.png`.

---

**I've tried**

```
  @if(file_exists(public_path().'/images/photos/account/{{Auth::user()->account_id}}.png'))
    <img src="/images/photos/account/{{Auth::user()->account_id}}.png" alt="">
  @else
    <img src="/images/photos/account/default.png" alt="">
  @endif
```

---

**Result**

It kept load my **default** image while I'm 100% sure that `1002.png` is exist.

How do I properly check if that file is exist ?

Comment: You echo the result of `public_path().'/images/photos/account/{{Auth::user()->account_id}}.png'` and check if it's even valid path. If yes, then you go and look whether it really exists. You already know it doesn't, computers don't lie.

Comment: @RyanVincent : return `false`.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting that? There is no way you can get it.

Comment: I got the string. You're right. I have to fix my concatenation. See my solution. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @ihue Kindly accept the solution if it has worked for you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Solution**

```
      @if(file_exists( public_path().'/images/photos/account/'.Auth::user()->account_id.'.png' ))
        <img src="/images/photos/account/{{Auth::user()->account_id}}.png" alt="">
      @else
        <img src="/images/photos/account/default.png" alt="">
      @endif
```

Comment: @MarceloAgimóvel its juts laravel structure.
Blade is the simple, yet powerful templating engine provided with Laravel

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

Comment: Blade it's a template language. I prefer storage my application checks and logical in classes,  middelwares or something similar and reusable;  not in views.

Answer (score 70):

Wherever you can, try and reduce the number of `if` statements. For example, I would do the following:

```php
// User Model
public function photo()
{
    if (file_exists( public_path() . '/images/photos/account/' . $this->account_id . '.png')) {
        return '/images/photos/account/' . $this->account_id .'.png';
    } else {
        return '/images/photos/account/default.png';
    }     
}

// Blade Template
<img src="{!! Auth::user()->photo() !!}" alt="">
```

Makes your template cleaner and uses less code. You can also write a unit test on this method to test your statement as well :-)

Comment: `public_path("/images/photos/account/{$this->account_id}.png")` is a shorter and more readable way to write the condition.

Answer (score 32):

Check if file exists on action with "File::" and pass the resut to the view

```
$result = File::exists($myfile);
```

Comment: From where should the `File` be imported?

Comment: You can just do \File as its a facace

Comment: `Illuminate\Support\Facades\File` is a facade for `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem`

Answer (score 14):

In Laravel 5.5, you can use the `exists` method on the storage facade:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem

```
$exists = Storage::disk('s3')->exists('file.jpg');
```

You could use a ternary expression:

```
$file = ($exists) ? Storage::disk('s3')->get('file.jpg') : 
         Storage::disk('s3')->get('default.jpg');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
@if(file_exists('uploads/users-pic/'.auth()->user()->code_melli.'.jpg'))

    <img src="{{'/uploads/users-pic/'.auth()->user()->code_melli.'.jpg'}}"

class="img-circle" alt="{{auth()->user()->name}}" width="60" height="60">

@else
    <img src="/assets/images/user-4.png" width="60" height="60" class="img-circle img-corona" alt="user-pic" />
@endif
```

as you can see in above code when you want to check image don't use '/' at the first of you path

```
 @if(file_exists('uploads/users-pic/'.auth()->user()->code_melli.'.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the of the file in the database.If the image path exist

```
<?php
$path = "packages/pathoffile/img/media/" . $filename;
$media = isset($media) ? $media : ""; //If media is saved
?>
@if($media == "")
<img src='../packages/defaultimagelocation/assets/img/user.png' />
@else
<img src='../packages/originalmedialocation/img/media{{ $media }}' />
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( !(Storage::exists('order/'.$details['photo'])) )
{
   Storage::copy($details['photo'], 'order/'.$details['photo']);
}
```

```
use Storage;
```

top of contorller.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Storage::disk('<your storage disk >')->exists('<path (from disk to file existing directory name)>/<filename>') {
     Storage::disk('<your storage disk >')->delete('<path (from disk to file existing directory name)>/<filename>');
}

//Sample code
    
$post = Post::findOrFail(1);
    
if (Storage::disk('public')->exists('post/images/'.$post->image)) {
     Storage::disk('public')->delete('post/images/'.$post->image));
}
```