# How to check if a file exists in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, file-exists

I have tried the following method to check if file exist:

```
@if(file_exists(public_path('/user_img/'.Auth::user()->id.'.jpg')))
```

It returns `false` even when the file exists!

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining If a File Exists in Laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028575/determining-if-a-file-exists-in-laravel-5)

Comment: check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028575/determining-if-a-file-exists-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have corrected by adding curly braces to the `User id` and it works fine:

```
@if(file_exists(public_path().'user_img/{{ Auth::User()->id }}.jpg'))
```

Comment: Am new to Laravel so I wasn't sure If this works but the problem was just the syntax

Comment: Please check it as answered

Answer (score 1):

First you have to mention  **use File** at top of the page

```
$imagepath = "1.jpg";

$directoryPath = 'user_img/'.$imagepath;

if(File::exists($directoryPath)){
    //echo "n exist"; die();
} else {  echo "not exists";   }
```

Comment: Came here by Google, +1 because it's a Laravel solution, not default PHP.