# file_exists not working in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem, [I have already read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028575/determining-if-a-file-exists-in-laravel-5), unfortunately though, the answers given to me do not work.

I wish that when no picture is found, he prints the placeholder image.

```
Models:
public function cover()
      {
         if(file_exists('/upload/cover/'.$this->immagine)) {
             return url('/upload/cover/'.$this->immagine);
         } else {
             return url('/upload/cover/no-cover.png');
         }
      }

Blade:
            <img src="{!! $info_giochi->cover() !!}"
            <img src="{{ url('upload/cover/'.$info_giochi->immagine) }}">
```

As you can see, in the blade I put the src twice, this to verify that the image I'm referring to really exists, in fact there.

Why, in my first img src, does the "no-cover.png" and not the image appear?

Comment: Why you don't use `public_path()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found my mistake...

Comment: file_exists uses the filesystem so `/upload` literally means the upload directory in the root path of the server not the web directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
public function cover()
  {
     if(file_exists(public_path('/upload/cover/'.$this->immagine))) {
         return '/upload/cover/'.$this->immagine;
     } else {
         return '/upload/cover/no-cover.png';
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the "Storage" facade for this purpose it will be more "Laravel-way".

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('public')->exists('/upload/cover/' . $this->immagine);
```

See the ["Storage" documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem)