# The blade only load the default picture?

Tags: php, image, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I have seen this answer [
  [[Determining If a File Exists in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028575/determining-if-a-file-exists-in-laravel-5][1]and) and tried to implement the same method in my project.

I'm using Imageintervention and Laravel 5.4. I have a PropertyController with the following validation code:

```
 //? file upload

     if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = time() .'.' .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('/imgs/properties/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(400, 300)->save($location);
        $property->image = $filename;

     }
     //store in the DB
```

In my show blade i have the following syntax:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    @if(file_exists(public_path().'../imgs/properties/. $filename'))
     <img src="../imgs/properties/{{ $property->image }})" alt="">
      @else
      <img src="../dist/img/villa.jpg" alt="">
    @endif
```

I put the following code in my Property Model:

```
public function image()
 {
    if(file_exists( public_path() . '/imgs/properties/' . $filename)) {
        return '/imgs/properties/' . $filename;
    } else {
        return '../dist/img/villa.jpg';
    }
```

If I register a property with an image I only get the default image and not the newly registered image. I have checked in my properties folder and the image newly registered image is there waiting i fix the problem. Do you have any idea about what went wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: eith use `@if(file_exists('../imgs/properties/. $filename'))`  or `@if(file_exists(public_path().'/imgs/properties/. $filename'))`

Comment: Hello, Alive to Die!  I tried your suggestion and I got the same result. The default image is still there. Do you have any other idea about how to tackle this issue? Thank you very much in advance!