# Laravel 5.6:Check if a file exists

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems, storage

So i'm creating user profiles in laravel and want to show a generic profile image if the user hasn't uploaded his/her own profile image with the following if/else condition:

```
@if(false)
    <img src="img/uploads/avatars/{{$user->Uname}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{$user->Uname}}'s Profile Pic">
@else
    <img src="img/uploads/avatars/{{$user->avatar}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{$user->Uname}}'s Profile Pic">
@endif
```

I need to check if a file exists with the same name as the user-name of a user (uploads create a file with that name in the above specified location).The false is where the condition for file existence should be but i'm facing 2 problems that i haven't found in other solutions:

1. The file exists in a path outside of storage. (it exists in public
   folder)
2. I want to do it without the use of storage or file facades.

Note: Following changes have been made to filesystems.php

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('../public/img/uploads/'),
        ]
```

Edit: The problem is similar to the one mentioned here but this solution didn't work for me:[Determining If a File Exists in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028575/determining-if-a-file-exists-in-laravel-5)

Edit#2:
Final Working Code:

```
@if(is_file("img/uploads/avatars/{$user->Uname}"))
<img src="img/uploads/avatars/{{$user->Uname}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{$user->Uname}}'s Profile Pic">
@else
<img src="img/uploads/avatars/default.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{$user->Uname}}'s Profile Pic">
@endif
```

Comment: What about `@if(is_file('/path/to/file.ext'))`?

Comment: I have done something similar with 2 javascript functions triggered by class names. I can post them if you want. But I won't reconstruct them to your specific needs. First the picture loads as a regular html request. If that fails, the js is triggered. You can look at how many places you like to find and show the pic. While searching it shows a font awesome loading icon.

Comment: I don't know where images are stored in system. It is something you have to check in method that holds the code of upload/saving the image. Just use that. After all it's just a string.

Comment: @Tpojka, it works, if you add your comment as an answer i will mark it as correct.

Comment: Added. Please check if works. I didn't test it though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should check if file exists

```
@if(is_file('/path/to/file.ext'))
    // code
@else
    // code
@endif
```

You could use laravel helpers, something like:

```
@if(is_file(public_path('img/uploads/avatars/' . $user->Uname)))
    //<img src="{{ asset('img/uploads/avatars' . $user->Uname) }}">
```

Comment: It does work, i've added the working solution to my question as well now, thanks alot.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have your file extension in your image src.

```
@if(file_exists('img/uploads/avatars/'.$user->Uname.'png')) 
  <img src="img/uploads/avatars/{{$user->Uname}}.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{$user->Uname}}'s Profile Pic">
@else
    <img src="img/uploads/avatars/{{$user->avatar}}.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{$user->Uname}}'s Profile Pic">
@endif
```

Use '.png' or '.jpg' as per your needs.