# How to check from full image url that the image exists in storage folder or not in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have stored full url of image when store the image in database.

```
$image = $request->hasFile('thumbnail') ? Storage::disk('public')->put('templates', $request->file('thumbnail')) : null;
'thumbnail' => Storage::disk('public')->url($image)
```

Now I need to check if the image exists in storage templates folder or not.
when retrieve `http://my-domain//storage/templates/vglZJtHqvNrp5gD6p7A9KL79CIGG2KIn2Pe1e8po.png`that i got in image.
How can i check this?

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028575/determining-if-a-file-exists-in-laravel-5)

Comment: file_exist(storage_path('/templates/vglZJtHqvNrp5gD6p7A9KL79CIGG2KIn2Pe1e8po.png')); ?

Answer (score 0):

2 Approach you can use but i need to know the exact directory path, public/templates/.. or storage/templates/..

Method 1

```
file_exists(storage_path('/templates/vglZJtHqvNrp5gD6p7A9KL79CIGG2KIn2Pe1e8po.png')); //Storage_path or public_path
```

Method 2

```
$exists = Storage::disk('public/templates/')->exists('vglZJtHqvNrp5gD6p7A9KL79CIGG2KIn2Pe1e8po.png'); //   public/templates/ or storage/templates
```

I would recommend the first method. (Updated typo on exist -> exists)

Comment: I don't know the image name that stored in storage folder. Know full image url

Comment: Check from your local project? the file name should be in your project under storage or public directory.

Comment: you have a typo: `file_exist` should be `file_exists`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply replace the base storage URL to get the path:

```
// use `url` to guarantee an absolute URL
$baseStorageUrl = url(Storage::url('/'));
$path = str_replace($baseStorageUrl, '', $imageURL);
$exists = File::exists('public' . $path);
```

(untested, but should work)