# How to prevent duplicate files in Subfolders - Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-10

I created a add view where multiple files can be upload at same time :
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtuoq.png)
The file path when file will be uploaded is like - Drawings/PartNumber/Type/filename.extension
How can I check in Drawing Folder any file cant not be same with extension like

1. Drawings/PartNumber1/Type1/filename1.pdf
2. Drawings/PartNumber2/Type2/filename1.pdf
3. Drawings/PartNumber1/Type3/filename1.pdf
4. Drawings/PartNumber1/filename1.pdf
5. Drawings/filename1.pdf
   never will be accepted.

My function is :

```
public function AddNewPart(Request $request)
    {
if (array_key_exists('DrawingFile',$data)) {
                foreach($request->file('DrawingFile') as $key=>$file)
                {
                    if ($data['fileupload_ID'][$key]==NULL) {
                        $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        $file_name2 = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                        $filepath='Drawings/'.$data['PartNumber'].'/'.$data['Type'][$key].'/'.$file_name2;
                        $file->move(public_path('Drawings/'.$data['PartNumber'].'/'.$data['Type'][$key].'/'), $file_name2);
                        $DocumentData2=array('Type'=>$data['Type'][$key],'fcontent'=>$file_name2,'condpartno'=>$data['PartNumber'],'fname'=>$filepath,
                        'DrawingNo'=>$data['DrawingNo'][$key],'DocumentType'=>$data['Type'][$key]);
                        DB::table('fileupload')->insert($DocumentData2);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: **Never** use the user-supplied filename to store  the uploaded file in the file-system.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php?

Comment: Which filenames should not be accepted? It is totally confusing for now!

Comment: Does this already answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/34028575/367456 - if not, [edit] your question and provide clarifications what you've tried, where you got stuck and what you current understanding is to add more context.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

public function AddNewPart(Request $request)
    {
       if (array_key_exists('DrawingFile',$data)) {
            $files_info = [];
            foreach (File::allFiles(public_path('Drawings')) as $file) {
                array_push($files_info,$file->getFilename());
            }
            if (array_key_exists('DrawingFile',$data)) {
                $drawingName = [];
                foreach($request->file('DrawingFile') as $key=>$file)
                {
                    array_push($drawingName,$file->getClientOriginalName());
                }                $trdarray=array_merge($files_info,$drawingName);
                if (count($trdarray) !== count(array_unique($trdarray))) {
                    return redirect()->back()->with('error','Drawing File is already exist!');
                }
            }
            foreach($request->file('DrawingFile') as $key=>$file)
                {
                    if ($data['fileupload_ID'][$key]==NULL) {
                        $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        $file_name2 = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                        $filepath='Drawings/'.$data['PartNumber'].'/'.$data['Type'][$key].'/'.$file_name2;
                        $file->move(public_path('Drawings/'.$data['PartNumber'].'/'.$data['Type'][$key].'/'), $file_name2);
                        $DocumentData2=array('Type'=>$data['Type'][$key],'fcontent'=>$file_name2,'condpartno'=>$data['PartNumber'],'fname'=>$filepath,
                        'DrawingNo'=>$data['DrawingNo'][$key],'DocumentType'=>$data['Type'][$key]);
                        DB::table('fileupload')->insert($DocumentData2);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```